# Why is my Bosch drill working intermittently?

Tags: electrical, switch, drill

My cordless Bosch drill/driver will only work the first time the switch is pressed after attaching the battery. As soon as I release the pressure, it won’t work again until I remove the battery and replace it. Then, once again, it only works the first time the switch is pressed, and then... Nothing. Highly infuriating! It’s exactly the same with different batteries, so I don’t think it’s a battery problem. The problem is the same in forward and reverse, and in drill and screwdriver functions. Please can anyone help diagnose the fault? I’d be really grateful! Thank you.

Comment: sounds like a protection circuit failing, which loss of power resets. It's likely going to be hard (expensive) to diagnose and fix. A cheap work around is a normally-on button that handily disconnects the battery...

Comment: If its green, you have a one year warranty, if its blue it will have a two or three year warranty. At least, that's how it works in my part of the world.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies! My drill's green, and unfortunately out of warranty. Dandavis, please could you kindly explain what you mean? Don't fancy having to shell out for a new drill... :( Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I emptied half I can of aerosol contact cleaner into it, vents, trigger chuck ect, goes well again